# I have a problem with my Django URL pattern naming

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls, url-pattern

For whatever reason when I give a name="..." - argument to a URL pattern and I want to refer to it by using the name it does not seem to work. 
That's my 'webapp/urls.py' file:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import PostListView, PostDetailView, PostCreateView
from .import views

app_name = 'webapp'
urlpatterns = [
    path("", PostListView.as_view(), name="webapphome"),
    path("post/<int:pk>/", PostDetailView.as_view(), name="postdetail"),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name="postcreate"),
    path("about/", views.About, name="webappabout"),
]
```

And that's my 'webapp/views.py' file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView
from .models import Post


def Home(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all()    }
    return render(request, "webapp/home.html", context)

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'webapp/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date']

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'webapp/detail.html'

class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']
    template_name = 'webapp/postform.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

def About(request):
    return render(request, "webapp/about.html", {'title': 'About'})
```

And that's my 'webapp/models.py' file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("postdetail", kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

As you can see, I'm using the name 'postdetail' I've given to the URL path from PostDetailView but however I receive an Error like this when I create a new Post:

```
NoReverseMatch at /post/new/
Reverse for 'postdetail' not found. 'postdetail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: POST
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you read the Namespace section in Django Documentation, [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/)

The issue is due to you having an `app_name = 'webapp'` but not using it with `postdetail`

The objective of app_name is to ensure you know where to redirect if you have two url in different apps with same names.

change

```
return reverse("postdetail", kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

to

```
return reverse("webapp:postdetail", kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Comment: You don't know how happy I am right now... Thank you so much, it worked!

Comment: Glad it worked. Django only gets easier with time. Welcome to Stackoverflow